# Add validation in acts_as_commentable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-commentable

I'm using a gem called [acts_as_commentable](https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable)

I have added a custom column in the migration like: `recipient_id`

Then I generated a **Comment** model as per documentation:

`rails g comment`

Now, in my **Comment.rb**, I have following line:

```
validate :comment, :recipient_id, :presence => true
```

**Note: `comment` column is already added by gem itself**

Still, after following documentation, when I fire the following deliberately:

```
commentable = Post.create(:title => ......)
comment = commentable.comments.create
comment.comment = "Some comment"
comment.recipient_id = nil
comment.save!
```

The comment object seems like:

```
<Comment id: 1, comment: "Some comment", commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: "Post", recipient_id: nil, created_at: "2015-06-13 09:41:23", updated_at: "2015-06-13 09:41:23">
```

Why it's not validating presence of `recipient_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are calling `validate` instead of `validates`. They both are different.

It should be:

```
validates :comment, :recipient_id, :presence => true
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have asked a dumbest question ever. But, I think in this case I cannot add any validations because, as the doc suggests, it creates a empty comment object and then assigns the values, which will be restricted by validation. Don't know how to validate then?

Comment: Validations are run before the record is saved. It doesn't matter if you are mass assigning values or creating an empty object and then assigning values. It should work in your case.

Comment: Creation of empty object is not possible here as validation won't allow `recipient_id` to be nil in the first place

Comment: By creating an empty object I meant using `new` method. Building object would have been more appropriate. :)